# WSL2 can not access windows ip (retreived by `ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}` )

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Test code:

```
winip=$(ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
ping $winip
```

result:
[image]

Actually I want to use a proxy service host on windows .  I saw many people success with above command, why I faied ? Or wsl2 go into new problem ?

Comment: Are you positive your using WSL 2.  WSL 2 can only be used if you have an Insider Preview build installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I just can't wait to tried wsl2

Comment: Which WSL distribution? Why do you have an IP like `172.26.48.1` which belongs to an ISP on the internet at Los Angeles. This is not a local IP. You should be getting your router's local IP instead. Might be a bug in WSL2.

Comment: @harrymc  This is local IP,  if you search around `wsl2  access windows service` , you would find a lot IP like this .

Comment: It should be something like `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x`, depending on the router. Something is wrong in your WSL2.

Comment: @harrymc No you are wrong, cat /etc/resolv.conf can show this too . Fresh installed ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK. Thanks to the kindness of this site owner https://lengthmin.me/posts/wsl2-network-tricks/ .

I find it is due to windows firewall ...
But seems add wsl2 path to whitelist doesn't take effect, need shutdown firewall down to work around the problem.

---

Thanks to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585#issuecomment-610061194

This is the solution

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow
```

Comment: The answer did not work for me. But there is another trick below in the thread which actually helped: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585#issuecomment-1368330467